# difference between c++ code and python code for reading /dev/fb0 linux ubuntu16.4

Tags: python, c++, io

I am trying to convert some c++ code into python for my project.
but I am not getting the same output from both codes.

so the c++ code is

```cpp
 int fd_frbuf;
 fd_frbuf = open("/dev/fb0", O_RDWR|O_SYNC);
 printf("%d\n", fd_frbuf); 
 if (fd_frbuf < 1) {
     printf("Invalid fb0 device file\n");
 }
```

the output is 3.

and my python code is

```
 fd_frbuf = open("/dev/fb0", "r+b")
 print(fd_frbuf.read())
```

output is nothing, so my check for fb0 is available or not by doing `"< 1"` is always false.

I have tried,

1. ```
   fd_frbuf =  os.open("/dev/fb1", os.O_RDWR|os.O_SYNC)
   print(os.read(fd_frbuf, 1)
   ```
2. tried to print differently,

   ```
   print(struct.unpack('i', fd_frbuf.read(4))[0])

   print(np.fromfile(fd_frbuf, dtype=np.uint32))
   ```

how can I read this file so that I get the same output as c++?

Comment: Your C++ code isn't reading from the file. Why are you calling `.read()` in the Python version?

Comment: This will help you: [Read file line by line using ifstream in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line-using-ifstream-in-c)

Comment: @melpomene  Because  I was just troubleshooting . Basically I want to have same value as I got with c++ code (3). Otherwise my if condition (fd_frbuf< 1) will false in python. I am new in python so .read() printing was my first approach for troubleshooting.

Comment: So ... `print(fd_frbuf.fileno())`? You don't need to check for errors manually; `open` will throw an exception for you.